# Navigation Drawer header Imageview not getting updated

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, navigation-drawer, picasso

I am trying to load an image from a fragment using callback interface to the navigation drawer header. I debugged the application to find out that the string url passed is valid but picasso is unable to load the image in the header Imageview.

this is my callback interface code:

```
    @Override
public void changeUserStatus(boolean isLogin, String email,String profilePhotoUrl) {
    if (isLogin) {
        logoutBTN.setText(R.string.logout);
        //Toast.makeText(MainScreenActivity.this,email,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        userEmail.setText(email);
    }

    if (!profilePhotoUrl.equals("")) {
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(profilePhotoUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.logo).noFade().into(navImageView);
    }
    else {
        navImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
    }
}
```

this is the xml layout for my navigation header ImageView:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo">
        </de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView>
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/email_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/logoutBTN"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:text="@string/login_txt"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have initialised the navigation header ImageView in my Activities onCreate():

```
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header);
    View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    userEmail = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.email_header);
    logoutBTN = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.logoutBTN);
    navImageView = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: add a image loading listener to picasso and see what's the issue in loading

Comment: what is your `profilePhotoUrl`?

Comment: its a png image

Answer (score 1):

When I ran into problems with that kinda thing I add an Android id to the actual navigation view itself, then initialize a variable to NavigationView right before the navigation header initialization like so.

```
View navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View navHead = (NavigationHeader) navView.getHeaderView(0);
Textview tvEmail = (TextView) navHead.findViewById(R.id.userEmail); 
tvEmail.setText("theusersemail@whatever.com");
```